# Postgresql autovacuum to prevent wraparound stuck on corrupt table

Tags: postgresql, corruption, autovacuum

I have a process running that can not be killed safely:
autovacuum: VACUUM public.mytable (to prevent wraparound)

This table has been cleared (aside from some entries that can not be deleted due to the table's corruption during a hardware issue) and can not be dropped, because the vacuum is blocking this. I had to run a kill -9 to stop this process and restarted the database, but you can't disable this autovacuum (to prevent [transaction] wraparound), so the autovacuum is coming back up and immediately getting stuck by this corrupt table.

Any insight into this?

Comment: What's the error raised when trying to drop the table?

Comment: It hangs because it waits for the vacuum on the table to complete, but seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, shutdown database server and make a physical copy of data directory to a safe place. 
Then you could truncate the datafile of corrupted table. E.g.:

```
--Get datafile path
db=# SELECT pg_relation_filepath('corrupted_table');
 pg_relation_filepath 
----------------------
 base/1234/56789
(1 row)
```

1. Enter database directory (e.g: data/base/1234)
2. Rename the file to 56789_bkp
3. Create an empty file called 56789: `touch 56789`
4. Start database server
5. Issue a truncate table to force PostgreSQL overwrite datafile: `TRUNCATE TABLE corrupted_table;`
6. You may want to VACUUM and make a backup afterwards

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, will try this tomorrow after processing is complete.

Comment: Had to hold off until just now to try this.
* Shut down the database,
* Moved the file base/16385/24986 to a back up,
* Created an empty base/16385/24986 file,
* Restarted the database,
* And attempted the truncate.

This also blocked due again to the autovacuum being stuck on the same table.  Likely this is because of off-shoots of this table file:

$ ls 24986*
24986
24986.1
24986.2
24986_bkp
24986_fsm
24986_vm